# Insert Character into NSString or convert to intValue

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Probably very simple but I'm banging my head trying to figure it out.

I have this string, either as `NSMutableString` or just `NSString`.

```
-(NSMutableString *)timeSet{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeSet"];
}
```

Which I'm then outputting using this:

```
arguments[curArg++]=(char *)[[self timeSet] UTF8String];
```

And I need to insert a hyphen to the front of the output. So if the value of timeSet is twelve it is read as -twelve.

Comment: FYI - Do not use `valueForKey:`, use `objectForKey:` to get an object from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Thank you! Updated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", 'your otput here'];
```

And your method will look like this:

```
   -(NSString *)timeSet{

        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeSet"]];
    }
```

Comment: And see I knew it was something extremely simple. That worked like a charm, thank you sir.

Comment: @seventeenfive No problem.

Comment: Or you can use `return [@"-" stringByAppendingString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"timeSet"]];`.